# R Markdown + bib file: unused argument error

Tags: r-markdown, citations

My `.rmd` file fails to compile when including citations as a `.bib` file. 
I attached the code and error message here and very appreciate if someone could help.

[image]

Comment: Please can you add the code question, correctly formatted instead of an image? https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186/387544

Answer (score 1):

The indentation of the YAML options is important. You currently have `bibliography` within the `output` section, but it should be placed in as a top-level YAML.

```
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
bibliography: bib.bib
```

**Edit**: Make sure you have moved the bibliography out of the `pdf_document` options completely, as follows:

```
author: "Author"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
    fig_caption: yes
    number_sections: yes
bibliography: bib.bib
---
```

Comment: Hi, Mikey. I did place the bibliography on the top-level YAML as your suggestion, but it still doesn't work.  The error message was same as shown in the above figure. However, it run well if removing the **bibliography**.  Any further suggestion?  Thanks.

Comment: Updated the answer to resolve what I think you have done wrong. I am always happy to help new users, but it would help you if you were to read the guidance about asking questions on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Most importantly for you, you need to be able to provide a code example which allows others to replicate your problem. Attaching a screenshot just requires other people to manually type out the code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Writing better questions will make it easier for people to help

Comment: Many thanks, Mikey. Finally! I got it going through. I think the problem was incorrect pathways for the .bib file and did not place the bibliography on the top-level YAML.  Thanks again.  Erjia